# Build a view model for c# using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have one view model and i'm pass that view model into controller, but one of the model property is a list of other class. so i'm not able to bind it via jQuery.

I have the following view model.

```
public class ToolsAddViewModel
{
        public string Tools_Name { get; set; }
        public string Tools_Desc { get; set; }
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }
        public List<ToolsParamsBlockViewModel> Params_List { get; set; }
}
```

ToolsParamsBlockViewModel class that is used as list type

```
public class ToolsParamsBlockViewModel
{
        public int Params_ID { get; set; }
        public string Params_CSS_Attribute { get; set; }
        public int Params_Priority { get; set; }
}
```

here is my controller method that handle viewmodel data

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(ToolsAddViewModel toolsAddViewModel)
{
    //insert viewmodel data into database 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tools");
}
```

and finally im trying to add data into viewmodel using jQuery, here it is. im use table for add list into `Params_List` property.

```
$("#btnSave").on("click", function () {
        var ParamsList = [];
        $('#paramsBlockTable tbody > tr').each(function () {
                var SingleParams = [];
                $(this).find("input,select").each(function () {
                    SingleParams.push($(this).val());
                    console.log(values);
                });
                ParamsList.push(values);
        });
        var ToolsModel = {
                "ID": $("#ID").val(),
                "Tools_Name": $("#Tools_Name").val(),
                "Category_ID": $("#Category_ID").val(),
                "Params_List": ParamsList,
                "ScriptFiles_IDs": $("#ScriptFiles_IDs").val(),
                "Tools_SEO_Keyword": $("#Tools_SEO_Keyword").val(),
                "Tools_Desc": $("#Tools_Desc").val(),
        }
        console.log(ToolsModel);
});
```

here in `ParamsList` have array of table row elements but i need it into view model format.
thanks in advance

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you have `ToolsViewModel ` in  `public ActionResult Manage(ToolsViewModel toolsViewModel)` but your class is called `ToolsAddViewModel`

Comment: Shouldn't `ParamsList.push(values);` be `ParamsList.push(SingleParams);` and `console.log(values);` be `console.log(SingleParams);` ? I don't think this is the problem though. `SingleParams` should really be an object with properties: `Params_ID`, `Params_CSS_Attribute` and `Params_Priority` to match your server side model.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen you are right because I have used inheritance so I have just inherited that from another class. now i'm edit that.

Comment: @phuzi I have changed ```console.log(values);``` to ```console.log(SingleParams);``` but how can i assign object with property?

Comment: here is data that logged into console. [link](https://ibb.co/9qMNrGw)

Comment: You haven't shown us the accompanying HTML but I hope that the inputs have some property/attribute that would allow you to differentiate between the fields. Then you can declare `SingleParams` as an object => `var SingleParams  = { Params_ID = null, Params_CSS_Attribute = null, Params_Priority = null}` then you can assign individual values from the inputs.

Comment: You could also use the order of values to determine which value maps to which property.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], in the question itself, including the rendered HTML on which the script runs and and logs (as text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks [phuzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592958/phuzi) its work for me :)

here I have changed some code block.

```
$("#btnSave").on("click", function () {
    var ParamsList = [];
    $('#paramsBlockTable tbody > tr').each(function () {
        let SingleParams = {
            Params_ID: $(this).find(".params-id").val(),
            Params_CSS_Attribute: $(this).find(".params-attribute").val(),
            Params_Priority: $(this).find(".params-priority").val()
        }
        ParamsList.push(SingleParams);
    });

    var ToolsModel = {
        "ID": $("#ID").val(),
        "Tools_Name": $("#Tools_Name").val(),
        "Category_ID": $("#Category_ID").val(),
        "Params_List": ParamsList,
        "ScriptFiles_IDs": $("#ScriptFiles_IDs").val(),
        "Tools_SEO_Keyword": $("#Tools_SEO_Keyword").val(),
        "Tools_Desc": $("#Tools_Desc").val(),
    }
    console.log(ToolsModel);
});
```